# Combining columns where row number/primary key is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have created a temporary table with a student_id and three values corresponding to that student_id, however because of the way I wrote the script, the student_id appears three times instead of one, here you van see pictures of what i mean.

Lets say the firs table is named `#temp_results`, what sql code can I use to convert it to the second picture.

It's mostly for a quick overview so it's fine if its saved in a different temporary table.

What I have Now

[image]

What I would want it to be

[image]

Comment: Please consider using `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` in your script, so you won't have to smash the records later to see the the results you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need aggregation :

```
select student_id, max(phase1), max(phase2), max(phase3)
from #temp_results t
group by student_id;
```